# rewrite url htaccess cakephp paginator

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cakephp-1.2

```
RewriteRule result/([^\.]+) /job/search/result?k=$1 [L]
```

i have this code working well with urls like this

```
www.example.com/job/search/result/keyword
```

will give me the result of "keyword"

but the problem is that cakephp paginator is generating a link
like this

result/page:2?k=keyword

how can i write a rule for that
to fix the problem, i tried this but without a luck

```
RewriteRule result\/page:([0-9]+)\?k=([^\.]+) /job/search/result/page:$1?k=$2   [L]
```

so my new rules are

```
RewriteRule result\/page:([0-9]+)\?k=([^\.]+) /job/search/result/page:$1?k=$2   [L]
RewriteRule result/([^\.]+) /job/search/result?k=$1 [L]
```

Comment: what is not working now?

Comment: if I used this rule only
    RewriteRule result/([^\.]+) /job/search/result?k=$1 [L]
the generated link will put
"page:2?k=keyword" inside the $1
which will get me an empty result
thats why i tried to write another rule

Comment: i get fine results with /result/keyword but nothing with /result/page:2?k=keyword

Comment: so how can i write a code to ignore the rule if the url has page:2,page:3 ...etc  in it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831223/custom-pagination-route-using-cakephp-2-3-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by adding a rewriting condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/job/search/result/page:
```

so that the rewrite rule will only respond to

```
/job/search/result/keyword
```